# Is it possible to pass args containing & char in python

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I was trying to do something like this

```
python something.py ThisIs&TheKindOfThing=4Input

import sys
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
```

This throws an exception, and we can inspect the values and see that

```
a = 'ThisIs'
```

and it appears the rest is rejected. I had a bit of a google search around that, but didn't find any match. Can anyone explain to me how I can pass in a parameter like this, or just tell me where the relevant documentation is. I can't imagine that there isn't an easy way to handle this.

Comment: That's probably the shell interpreting &. Try wrapping the argument is quotes.

Comment: That's almost certainly your shell, not Python - did you try _quoting_ the argument?

Comment: Yes, you're both right. It's just the shell. Sorry, I didn't expect that behavior at all. So I can write something like python a.py "Abc&cd=R&RT=z" "Abc&ef=G&RT=z" and everything just works